# Upgrade SQLiteDatabase Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am writing application which uses SQLite. At first, my database had only one table called `products`. Now I want to add one more table called `favouriteproduct_table`. I wrote `db.exec("create table fav_product")` command in the `onCreate` method, but my app is crashing saying that no table found for `Product_fav`.

This is my code before adding favourite_product_table.

```
   private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
   {

      OpenHelper(Context context) 
      {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
      {

          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, systemSerID TEXT, systemSerName TEXT, productID TEXT, productName TEXT, productDesc TEXT, productType TEXT, batchID TEXT, minVal TEXT, maxVal TEXT)");

      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
      {
         Log.w("Example", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
         onCreate(db);
      }

   }
```

Above code is working fine, but when I try to create a new table using the following code, my app crashes.

```
 private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
   {

      OpenHelper(Context context) 
      {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
      {

          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, systemSerID TEXT, systemSerName TEXT, productID TEXT, productName TEXT, productDesc TEXT, productType TEXT, batchID TEXT, minVal TEXT, maxVal TEXT)");
          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TOPUP_FAVOURITE + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, systemSerID TEXT, systemSerName TEXT, productID TEXT, productName TEXT, productDesc TEXT, productType TEXT, batchID TEXT, minVal TEXT, maxVal TEXT, imageid TEXT)");
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
      {
         Log.w("Example", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
         onCreate(db);
      }

   }
```

Comment: Consider using "_id" instead of "id" for your primary key, many Android adapters prefer that tables implement the column used in `BaseColumns` instead of using an arbitrary pkey name.

Answer (score 1):

Check your question what you have asked

> Now I want to add one more table called **favouriteproduct_table**

and then

> db.exec("create table **fav_product**")

and at last

> my app is crashing saying that no table found for **Product_fav**

Now see what is the error.

In three of your sentence tables are of different names.

DO you have all these tables(**favouriteproduct_table**, **fav_product**, **Product_fav**) different which each others?